# How to debug Lua code using Visual Studio

Tags: lua, lua-c++-connection

I have a win32 application and this is linked with Lua files. Both Lua and C++ files have bi-directional communication and can invoke function within each other.

I wanted to debug Lua code from Visual Studio IDE likewise what we do for C++ code. I have installed "BabeLua For 2012 V3.2.2.0" extension, but not able to debug...

I simply created a break point in Lua file and attached the code to my Win32 application, but it says that "No symbols have been loaded".

Please help me to understand where does the symbol files resides for Lua, or is there any other intuitive way to debug Lua scripts..

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

> is there any other intuitive way to debug LUA scripts.

You may try [ZeroBrane Studio IDE](https://studio.zerobrane.com), which supports debugging of Lua scripts included in other applications. See the [remote debugging section](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging) in the documentation for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for you input..I have installed this tool but didn't see any way to attach my LUA script to the existing win32 running application, as my win32 application make a call into LUA file and vice versa...

Comment: You need to add `require('mobdebug').start()` call to the Lua file you want to debug. It doesn't need to be the first file, but that line needs to be in the code to start debugging. If modification of the Lua source is not an option, try Decoda.